# How to calculate brightness in RGB or HSL color space?

Tags: python-3.x

I wonder how can I calculate brightness in RGB or HSL color space?

What is the formula of brightness?

for example if I have this rgb string

```
rgbstring='rgb(120,175,56)'
hslstring='hsl(257,47%,60%)'
```

how can I get the brightness of this color

Comment: What is your definition of "brightness"? Do you know what `R`, `G`, `B` and `H`, `S`, `L` mean? I see that you've asked a couple of very similar questions recently, but it doesn't seem that you've done much research on the topic.

Comment: I second @beaker 's opinion. Please let me ask, do you know the standard module `colorsys`?

Comment: @beaker Brightness means how bright is the color?

Comment: @gboffi I just want to know the formula

Comment: There are [several color attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Color-making_attributes) that could be called "brightness". You could be looking for Lightness from [HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), Value from [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_RGB) or Luma (Y') from [Y'UV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y′UV444_to_RGB888_conversion).